# Do I have to provide @3x images for displays like Sony's Xperia Z?

Tags: css, retina-display

Retina iPhones have a dpi of 326 while Xperia Z has a dpi of 443. Do I have to provide @3x images for suchlike devices to make images look sharp and crisp on them?

Comment: Yes, why not. That's good to do

Comment: Not necessarily (and is @3 even used??). Human eyes can only discern so much detail so it might just be a "waste of bandwidth (server cost and responsiveness), memory (client processing), and effort (your time)" without a relevant benefit to [enough] customers. Remember that size is a squared problem: @3 = *9x more pixels* than @1 (and > *2x more pixels* than @2). Just as with digital cameras, MP does not mean "better"! Also, devices will do their darnedest to make even LD graphics look "sharp".

Comment: Interesting reads of random assortment http://alistapart.com/article/mo-pixels-mo-problems , http://spigotdesign.com/2012/07/svg-test/